# MPAndroidChart Stacked BarChart Custom Markerview Nullpointer exception

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am having a problem with the custom marker example I replicated exactly and set it on my Stacked Barchart but when I click on it I get an exception.

The code is exactly the same as as [example](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/MarkerView).

The exception I get looks like this:

```
12-22 15:28:54.052 12901-12901/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                               Process: com.myapp.myapp, PID: 12901
                                               java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'float com.github.mikephil.charting.highlight.Range.to' on a null object reference
                                                   at com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarLineChartBase.getMarkerPosition(BarLineChartBase.java:571)
                                                   at com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.Chart.drawMarkers(Chart.java:598)
                                                   at com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarLineChartBase.onDraw(BarLineChartBase.java:252)
                                                   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15114)
                                                   at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14048)
                                                   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14071)
                                                   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14838)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3404)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
                                                   at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14043)
                                                   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14071)
                                                   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14838)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3404)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
                                                   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15117)
                                                   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.draw(ViewPager.java:2262)
                                                   at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14048)
                                                   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14071)
                                                   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14838)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3404)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
                                                   at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14043)
                                                   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14071)
                                                   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14838)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3404)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
                                                   at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14043)
                                                   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14071)
                                                   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14838)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3404)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
                                                   at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14043)
                                                   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14071)
                                                   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14838)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3404)
                                                   at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.drawChild(DrawerLayout.java:1229)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
                                                   at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14043)
                                                   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14071)
                                                   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14838)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3404)
                                                   at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.drawChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1077)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
                                                   at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14043)
                                                   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14071)
                                                   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14838)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3404)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
                                                   at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14043)
                                                   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14071)
                                                   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14838)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3404)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
                                                   at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14043)
                                                   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14071)
                                                   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14838)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3404)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
                                                   at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14043)
                                                   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14071)
                                                   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14838)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3404)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
                                                   at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:14043)
                                                   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:14071)
                                                   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14838)
                                                at android.view.
```

Someone has any idea?

**EDIT**

So this is the `onValueSelected(..)`.

```
    @Override
    public void onValueSelected(Entry e, int dataSetIndex, Highlight h) {
        barChart.highlightValue(e.getXIndex(), dataSetIndex);
    }
```

Comment: Post your java code of click.

Comment: I posted the `onValueSelected(..)` @Beena

Comment: you didnot initialize the barChart object

Comment: @Radix The whole chart is working already for a while but it just breaks down at the moment of selecting. I used `setDrawHighLightArrow();` and it works too but I want my custom arrow.

Comment: A complete stacktrace would be helpful to debug your problem. As of now the only thing we know is there is a NPE error.

Answer (score 1):

It would be good to anyway check if `Entry` is equal to zero as it is shown in the Stacked BarChart example.

This is the code from example:

```
@Override
public void onValueSelected(Entry e, int dataSetIndex, Highlight h) {

    BarEntry entry = (BarEntry) e;

    if (entry.getVals() != null)
        Log.i("VAL SELECTED", "Value: " + entry.getVals()[h.getStackIndex()]);
    else
        Log.i("VAL SELECTED", "Value: " + entry.getVal());
}
```